# FHIR : How to check whether the exposed JSON is in proper FHIR standard

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

We have created a patient resource using FHIR, is there any tool or mechanism to validate whether the created JSON Object is in proper FHIR standard ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [FHIR Validation](http://hl7.org/fhir/validation.html) from the FHIR Spec.

Comment: Please always include/quote the core of the answer from the link. If the link changes this answer won't be helpful anymore.

Comment: Well, yes, generally true but this is a controlled standard, the link won't change in non-useful ways

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it .... FHIR Validator using a jar

1.Install java 1.7
2.Download the jar from the link (https://fhir.github.io/latest-ig-publisher/org.hl7.fhir.validator.jar)
3.Double click the jar it will get installed 
4.Place the json of patient resource in a specific path and refer the path to the below command . if output of the resource validator is required then specify the path for that to.
***command :***
java -jar org.hl7.fhir.validator.jar c:\temp\patient.json -output c:\temp\validation.json

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HAPI and Java, you can use the `IParser.parseResource()` method, as shown [here](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/e76b1dacb343f99d89a0af4c1dda9570fa03701e/hapi-fhir-structures-dstu3/src/test/java/ca/uhn/fhir/parser/JsonParserDstu3Test.java#L68):

```java
        FhirContext fhirCtx = FhirContext.forDstu3(); // DSTU3
        IParser p = fhirCtx.newJsonParser();
        p.setParserErrorHandler(new StrictErrorHandler());

        try {
            p.parseResource(jsonAsString); // Pass your Patient's JSON string here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do something here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to run validation operation on supported FHIR resource,
with **precondition** to check FHIR server capability statement for support.
Example: `URL: [base]/Resource/$validate`

Check this HL7 FHIR post on validation: [Validate a resource](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/operation-resource-validate.html)